# Java Basics - Class-Structure and Code-Sharing

Tags: java, git, github, gist

I'm giving myself a try in Java (I want to make 6 weeks hardly learning anything I can in my free time, just to see if it fits me and how far this will go).

I'm on my 2nd day now and have some questions:

1) Is this (https://gist.github.com/Wumbaz/c7df6cbd95f7d48b8fa110b0d7133aa7) a common way to share my java project? How to let people review my code in another way?

2) If the Link above works, is this the common structure for projects? I have 2 important classes next to my main-function, so I decided that those will be 2 ".java-files" on their own. Is this "how it´s done"?

3) If someone really has time, I would be super happy for a general review of my lines. What could I have improved in this very simple project.

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Nico

Comment: take some time and know how and what to ask in SO community [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, github or github gists are a common way to share your code. However, I can see you have posted some XML configuration files from your IDE alongside with your code. Read about ignoring certain files: https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/

2) Generally yes, each Java class should be in a separate file. However, I would not really call it a "project structure", there is much more to that topic. According to the project you are making, you would separate your classes in specific packages. I recommend reading something about design patterns, for example here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/ . It might be a little confusing for you in the beginning, but once you improve your programming skills it will become very necessary.

3) If you want to improve your code quality do some research about "Clean Code". There is a great book with this title that every programmer should read, however it is a little bit more advanced and maybe not suitable in the beginning.

Comment: Amazing fast and helpful answear! Thanks a lot!